# django migrations error. I migrated model but changes not aplied

Tags: django, migration, migrate

i added new field to model and deleted another field but not deleting old field and not adding new feld.I deleted all migration files and re migrate it problem is same not working migration. It was a message " No migrations to apply.
[here is result after migrate app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgprT.png)
[here is my changed model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im6aW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to solve issue.

1. Run showmigrations. `python manage.py showmigrations` it should show all migration completed.
2. Undo the changes you have done in model i.e new field to model and deleted another field
3. Run makemigrations `python manage.py makemigrations`, then migrate it fake `python manage.py migrate --fake`
4. reapply the changes in model.
5. Run makemigrations `python manage.py makemigrations`, then migrate it fake `python manage.py migrate`